# Using .gitattributes as merge strategy in submodules

Tags: git, gitattributes

I have two main branches which have one submodule, but pointing to two different branches of this submodule.

What I want is to ignore any submodule change when I merge/rebase between the two main branches.

I'm trying to use `.gitattributes` to ignore any merge conflict for a submodule (named `internal`).

Currently I have `internal merge=ours` in `.gitattributes`, but it's not working, it fails merging the `internal` submodule.

There is any other merge strategy that I can apply for my needs? Or I'm doing something wrong in the `.gitattributes` usage?

Answer (score 3):

Submodules get recorded in the superproject as a *gitlink* entry.  The gitlink stores the raw hash ID that the superproject Git will use to command the submodule Git to `git checkout` in the submodule.  (Besides the gitlink, you also need the `.gitmodules` file content to supply additional information required for the initial clone, but once the clone has happened, these details have moved from the `.gitmodules` file to your superproject's configuration.  So the `.gitmodules` content becomes irrelevant: only the gitlink matters.)

A merge driver tells Git how to merge *files*.  A gitlink entry is not a file, so merge drivers have no effect here.  When Git is merging the three commits—the merge base and the two branch tips—and the merge base and the two branch tips all have different hash IDs stored in a gitlink, you will get a merge conflict and nothing you do will automatically resolve it.  You must manually resolve it.